# Hide Soft Keyboard

Tags: android

I need to be able to hide the soft keyboard in response to clicking a button.  I have seen numerous posts on this subject and it seems that the solution is to use the `InputMethodManager`, but I have been unable to get it to work for me.  Supposedly the following will hide the soft keyboard:

```
  InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) 
         getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

  inputManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(editView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

However, this is not working for me (can any suggest why?), and even if it did, I want to be able to hide the keyboard regardless of what view has the input, and I may not know what view that is.

I found that the call:

```
inputManager.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

will hide the keyboard if it is currently being shown.  Unfortunately it will also show it if it is currently hidden.  So for this to work for me, I would need a way to determine whether it is currently visible.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Well, duh!  I guess it would help if I called the correct function.  Thanks.