# giving null pointer when using InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to input this piece of code to hide the soft keyboard on the android, but it's returning a null pointer.

code:

```
public void testSetTestEnvironment (){
    solo.clickInList(4);
    solo.clickOnMenuItem(ConfigVariables.CATALOGSERVER);
    assertTrue(solo.searchText(ConfigVariables.CATALOGSERVERURL));


    //Enter KeyCode
     solo.clickInList(5);

    View myEditText = solo.getViews().get(0);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    solo.enterText(solo.getEditText(0), "");
    solo.enterText(0, ConfigVariables.KEYCODE);

    assertTrue(popupClickButtonHandler("Enter KeyCode", "OK"));
```

the logs show:

java.lang.NullPointerException

Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question about an exception, you will want to post the entire exception message and also indicate which line is causing it (usually with an obvious comment in the code). Otherwise you force us to guess, and we often guess wrong. Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow, by the way.

Comment: either imm or myEditText can be null, you must post stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little bit too late but I hope this is helpful for someone.
Your code is bug-prone because it relies on a focused view to get the window token from.

Try using:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

This code works correctly for me.

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429125/hiding-keyboard-after-calling-new-activity-that-shows-a-progressdialog) by [venator85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247095/venator85)